# How can I iterate a function with a parameter there the parameter is filename in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have 20 text files in a folder and I couldn’t find any solution how my main function which has only one parameter invoke those files(the extensions of files are “txt”). I tried with wildcard but I get always pathnames. My foldername is textfiles which includes 20 files and I can't have any argument either when I run the program.

Comment: Are you asking how to list the files in a directory in Common Lisp?

Comment: Use the [`DIRECTORY`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dir.htm#directory) function.

Comment: (directory "textfiles/*.txt")) gives me nil.

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname, `*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*` might not be what you expect.

Comment: You really need to say what implementation you're using.  Also report what `(namestring (merge-pathnames (pathname ...) *default-pathname-defaults*))` tells you, where `...` is one of the filenames, including the directory, that you think exists.

Comment: Helpers: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/files.html but please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
(defun my-func (dir)
    (setq pathname (make-pathname :name :wild :type "txt" :defaults (pathname dir)))
    (loop 
      for file in (directory pathname) do 
        (print (file-namestring file))))
```

If you want to print the full path of a file you can use namestring instead of file-namestring.

Comment: Thank you so much. But the path to my directory should be dinamically so when I submit it should work without changing the code

Comment: No problem. I have updated the code to do that. Now you can pass the directory either as a string or as a pathname.